# "git submodule foreach" does not iterate over all modules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to iterate a command over all of my submodules, but `git submodule foreach` skips many of them.

```
$ git submodule foreach pwd
Entering '.zprezto'
/Users/zachriggle/.zprezto
Entering 'omni'
/Users/zachriggle/omni
```

You can see that there are many more modules listed in .gitmodules

```
$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule ".bash_it"]
    path = .bash_it
    url = git://github.com/zachriggle/bash-it.git
[submodule ".zprezto"]
    path = .zprezto
    url = ssh://git@REDACTED/~zriggle/prezto.git
[submodule ".pyenv"]
    path = .pyenv
    url = git://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git
[submodule ".rbenv"]
    path = .rbenv
    url = git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git
[submodule "uncrustify"]
    path = uncrustify
    url = ssh://git@REDACTED/~zriggle/uncrustify.git
[submodule "omni"]
    path = omni
    url = ssh://git@REDACTED/~zriggle/omni.git
```

How do I get Git to iterate over ALL of the submodules?

Comment: Try running `git submodules update --init` first.

Comment: From doc: *"Any submodules defined in the superproject but not checked out are ignored by this command."*

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the repositories are not tracked by git, despite being in `.gitmodules`.

You must `git add subrepo`, in this case you must e.g.

```sh
git add .pyenv
git commit -m 'Add pyenv submodule'
```